# Как правильно написать incert в хранимой процедуре

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица Oracle, есть в ней триггер, он имеет ошибку, то есть он в состоянии invalid, так как в нем есть хранимая процедура, внутри которой есть `insert`. Так как я изменил саму таблицу, куда `insert` пишет даныне, мне нужно как то изменить `insert`, чтобы он правильно отработал. В бд новичок. Вот сама хранимая процедура.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE KANCHDATA.SetStructuraChanged IS
BEGIN
update dictionarytable set value=to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') where key='StructuraChangedDate';
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then
            insert into dictionarytable values ('StructuraChangedDate',to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),null);
            commit;
END SetStructuraChanged;
```

А вот сама таблица `dictionarytable`.

```
ALTER TABLE KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE
 DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE;

DROP TABLE KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE
(
  KEY                    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  VALUE                  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  LABID                  NUMBER(3),
  OID                    NUMBER,
  "OptimisticLockField"  INTEGER,
  "GCRecord"             INTEGER
)
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE_KEYLAB_IDX ON KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE
(KEY, LABID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   166
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE_PK ON KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE
(KEY)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   167
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

--  There is no statement for index KANCHDATA.SYS_C001131803.
--  The object is created when the parent object is created.

CREATE INDEX KANCHDATA."iGCRecord_DICTIONARYTABLE" ON KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE
("GCRecord")
LOGGING
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

CREATE INDEX KANCHDATA."iLABID_DICTIONARYTABLE" ON KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE
(LABID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE_CH_TRG 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
DECLARE
BEGIN
insert into tablechangehistory values ('DICTIONARYTABLE',sysdate,'');
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RAISE;
END DICTIONARYTABLE_CH_TRG;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE_TRG
BEFORE INSERT
ON KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- For Toad:  Highlight column OID
  :new.OID := DICTIONARYTABLE_SEQ.nextval;
END DICTIONARYTABLE_TRG;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM KANCHPROD.SYNP_DICTIONARYTABLE FOR KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE;


ALTER TABLE KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE ADD (
  PRIMARY KEY
  (OID)
  USING INDEX
    TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   2
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                NEXT             1M
                MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                PCTINCREASE      0
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               )
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

ALTER TABLE KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE ADD (
  CONSTRAINT DICTIONARYTABLE_LAB_FK 
  FOREIGN KEY (LABID) 
  REFERENCES KANCHDATA.LABS (LABID)
  ON DELETE SET NULL
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

GRANT SELECT ON KANCHDATA.DICTIONARYTABLE TO KANCHPROD;
```

Собственно вопрос, как мне правильно написать `insert`. Я хочу, чтобы процедура знала,что у меня теперь ключевое поле `oid` и заполняется оно через соответствующий сиквенс.
Как с синтаксисом у меня не получается. Пишу так

```
insert into dictionarytable(oid) values ('oid',(а дальше не получается)'StructuraChangedDate',to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),null);
            commit;
```

Comment: Да никак. Ну нельзя в триггере изменять таблицу, действие на которой инициировало триггер - ибо формально это может привести к зацикливанию (изменение запускает триггер, который выполняет изменение, которое инициирует триггер, который ... и так, пока сервер не ляжет). Вынесите всю логику на сервер, используйте процедуры вместо запросов, и проблема отпадёт.

Comment: В другой таблице все работает,так как в таблице dictionarytable не изменено ключевое поле.А тут оно добавлено и мне нужно как то добавить его в incert

Comment: @Akina Может, я проглядел, но я что-то не вижу, чтобы автор менял в триггере таблицу, на которой этот триггер висит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со вставками у вас одна и та же беда - вы не указываете столбцы, в которые вставлять данные, например:

```
insert into tablechangehistory values ('DICTIONARYTABLE',sysdate,'');
```

В принципе, так можно делать, но работает это до первого изменения таблицы, а потом всё валится (что, собственно, и случилось с другой таблицей). Лучше указывать столбцы явно:

```
insert into tablechangehistory (column1, column2, column3) 
values ('DICTIONARYTABLE',sysdate,'');
```

И в том запросе, с которым проблема, то же самое - вы указываете 1 столбец, а данные вставляете для 4 столбцов. Надо указать все столбцы:

```
insert into dictionarytable(<имя столбца>, <имя столбца>, <имя столбца>, oid) 
values ('oid', 'StructuraChangedDate', to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), null);
```

Следующей вашей проблемой будет то, что в этом запросе у вас 3 строковых значения, а строковых полей в таблице только два. То есть вы что-то где-то капитально путаете.

И на сдачу. Вот так писать не надо:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE KANCHDATA.SetStructuraChanged IS
BEGIN
update dictionarytable set value=to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') where key='StructuraChangedDate';
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then
            insert into dictionarytable values ('StructuraChangedDate',to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),null);
            commit;
END SetStructuraChanged;
```

`UPDATE` не выбрасывает исключение `NO_DATA_FOUND`. Если строка для изменения не найдется - просто ничего не произойдет. А даже если бы и происходило, все равно не надо так писать. Судя по смыслу, тут вам нужен `MERGE`:

```
merge into dictionarytable t1
using (select 'StructuraChangedDate' key, to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), value from dual) t2
   on (t1.key = t2.key)
 when matched then update
  set t1.value = t2.value
 when not matched then 
 insert (key, value, column123) values (t2.key, t2.value, null);
```

И последнее. Каждый раз, когда кто-то пишет так:

```
set value=to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

или так:

```
"OptimisticLockField"  INTEGER,
```

Или использует `commit` так, как это делаете вы - в мире умирает котенок. Помните об этом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, про котенка супер, а всетаки правильно то как надо написать,теряюсь я

Comment: Слишком долго писать... Вкратце - в первом случае вы храните дату как строку, хотя есть специальный тип `DATE` (используйте его), во втором случае название поля намекает на то, что вы его хотите использовать как флаг блокировки - у оракла есть свой механизм блокировок (используйте его), а коммит у вас используется просто неправильно, и тут даже в двух словах не скажешь (типа "используйте то-то"). Почитайте [Oracle Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/toc.htm), что ли... Раздел про транзакции.

Comment: Заработало все, благодаря вашему комментарию.